# What is the best coding strategy?

Tags: digital-communications, optimization, quantization, coding

There is a dataset of $N$ elements, each represented by $K$ bits. Now due to hardware limitations to reduce memory for storage, they have to be reprocessed into $K'$ bits each, and $K'<K$. What is the best coding strategy?

Comment: Do you have any information on the purpose, the distribution of values, etc.?

Comment: To reduce the memory for storage. A distribution may be derived from the N elements of the dataset.

Comment: "Best" induces a notion of "optimality". Do you have a quality criterion in mind? E.g. on the difference between the $K$ and the $K'$ version

Comment: @c1119 in general, what you want to do is not possible: if you could just take any sequence of bits and compress it, even just a little bit, then you could do the same with the result of the compression, again and again. That would mean you could compress an arbitrary huge amount of data to $K'$ bits, in the end. And that's impossible, because there's infinitely much potential data, but only $2^{K'}$ possible $K'$ long sequences. So, you need to answer Laurent's questions, if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: @LaurentDuval I'm not sure. Maybe in the sense of mutual information?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The original format of each data is K bits. The aim is to reduce each data to K' bits. Due to the limitation of hardware the transformation has to be done even it is lossy. Simply removing the lowest K-K' bits is possible, but is it the best way?

Comment: @c1119 Is $N$ relevant? I mean what is the difference if you have $2N$ elements? If $N$ is irrelevant, isn't this the classic source coding problem? In this case, if the entropy of your source is smaller than $K'$, many source coding technique can provide a lossless compression; if the entropy is greater than $K'$, this falls into the rate distortion framework for lossy compression.

Comment: @c1119 have you actually read my comment?

Comment: @AlexTP Huffman coding is variable length and the average length is K'. So it may be stored in the maximum length which may be larger than K'. For rate distortion coding, which method do you suggest?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did read your comment. But maybe I didn't get it. Sorry.

Comment: @c1119 I don't know much about it. Sorry.

Comment: @c119 you'll need to tell us about what kind of signal you have, and what your metric for quality is. There is no "universal lossy encoding" that works on all kinds of data and that is "best" for all purposes. You can't  just "lossy encode data"; you can " compress images " or "compress audio data" or "compress 3D point clouds from object scanning", but the processes/codes will be different for these different kinds of data, and they will be different depending on what you want to preserve and what you don't care as much about. "Best code" is specific to your kind of data and your application!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The case is soft channel bits stored to be combined with retransmission. But it is too big for storage. If given K', how to compress it? And maybe mutual information is a possible metric?

Comment: I'll stop interacting here. Without you telling us what you want to do with the data after retrieval from storage, we can't help you even tell what the things are which you might be willing to lose. Mutual information *can* be a possible metric, but what I'm asking you for several comments now is to define what the actual Sink is, i.e., what you need to do afterwards. The ultimate compression is just throwing the data away. Have you considered that, seeing that you can't pinpoint what you're doing with it once you retrieve it from storage?

Comment: @c1119 two comments (1) It is pretty sure that the metric cannot be mutual information because it measures the dependence between two random sources, whereas you are dealing with only one source here (2) I don't know what you will do with the *compressed* soft bits but if you want to combine them than feed them into conventional channel decoders, please note that these decoders are not designed for the lossily/losslessly-compressed softbits and, therefore, you need new decoders.

Comment: For (2), to the best of my knowledge, no one has done it, and the design is not trivial. If you really want to follow this approach, the optimal way (in the sense of information theory) is not compressing the softbits, but rather the joint source channel coding. I would suggest [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/files/2017-18/lecture_18.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1317). Note that the subject is advanced.

Comment: And if you know nothing about your data (softbits), then throwing away the least significant bits is optimal in the sense of minimizing the difference between the softbits before and after such a process. The proof is straightforward. The method has also the advantage that you can feed these "compressed" softbits into the conventional ML decoders because all softbits are scaled in the more or less same way.

Comment: @AlexTP and MarcusMuller I said in the comment above it is "soft channel bits stored to be combined with retransmission". Sorry it is not clear enough. If the channel decoder fails, soft channel bits are stored to be combined with later retransmission and the combined soft channel bits are fed into the channel decoder again. I wonder if there is a good strategy that the performance loss is little and the storage save is large.

Comment: @c1119 My three last comments did refer to the softbits, didn't they?

Comment: @AlexTP Yes. But why cann't mutual information be applied here? If the compression is lossy, then it's like passing through some channel or adding some noise. Mutual information can measure how much they are dependent?

Comment: @c1119 because your some channel or adding noise are random whereas your compression is deterministic and therefore the dependence is known. If the compression is lossless, the mutual information equals the entropy of the sources before and after compression. In the case of lossy compression, this magic mutual information falls back to the entropy of the compressed source.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" requires you to provide some quality metrics and these are in most cases highly dependent on your specific application.

Generally there are two classes of compression algorithm "lossless" and "lossy". Lossless leverages redundancies in the data and allows full recovery of the original data. Whether this works or not for you, depends on how much redundancy is in the data in the first place and what amount of compression you need.

"lossy" compressor are application specific. Examples are MP3 for audio signals or JPG for pictures. These are trying to minimize the perceptual effects of the data compression. Since audio and visual perception are completely different, so are the algorithms.

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: In none of the comments you have provided any information about what the data is. The best strategy depends on the type of data and the requirement of your specific application.

Comment: Sorry. I added a comment just now. Please see if it is clear enough.

Comment: Sorry no, it's not clear at all.

Comment: I'm sorry to make you confused. Please  tell me which statement is not clear.

Comment: Pretty much all of them. If you want to get an answer, you should edit a question and add  A LOT more detail: What's the data, what properties does it have and how is being used. How much compression do you need and what are you constraints (latency, cpu, memory, etc)